# Create a matrix from some given matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have this matrix to implement. Where user would define the value of dimensions ( p and N).

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADRJ7.png)

what would be the most efficient way to doing this in matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have a function to define `A(p)`, `B(p)`, and `C(p)` you can use [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) as follows:

```
F = @(N,p) kron(diag(ones(N,1)),A(p)) + ... 
           kron(diag(ones(N-1,1),1),B(p)) + ...
           kron(diag(ones(N-1,1),-1),C(p))
```

For example, if

```
A = @(p) ones(p);
B = @(p) 2*ones(p);
C = @(p) 3*ones(p);



>> F(4,2)

ans =

 1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0
 1     1     2     2     0     0     0     0
 3     3     1     1     2     2     0     0
 3     3     1     1     2     2     0     0
 0     0     3     3     1     1     2     2
 0     0     3     3     1     1     2     2
 0     0     0     0     3     3     1     1
 0     0     0     0     3     3     1     1
```